# In the context of natural language processing, can anyone give a concrete example of True Positive, True Negative, False Positive, False Negative?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, nlp

Google [post](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/true-false-positive-negative) gives a interesting explanation about True Positive, True Negative, False Positive, False Negative

> True Positive (TP): Reality: A wolf threatened. Shepherd said: "Wolf."
>   Outcome: Shepherd is a hero.
>
> True Negative (TN): Reality: No wolf threatened. Shepherd said: "No
>   wolf." Outcome: Everyone is fine.
>
> False Positive (FP): Reality: No wolf threatened. Shepherd said:
>   "Wolf." Outcome: Villagers are angry at shepherd for waking them up.
>
> False Negative (FN): Reality: A wolf threatened. Shepherd said: "No
>   wolf." Outcome: The wolf ate all the sheep.

In the context of CV, the classifier predicts if an image contains cat

```
True Positive (TP): 
Reality: an image contains cat. 
classifier predicts: cat.

True Negative (TN): 
Reality: an image does not contains cat. 
classifier predicts: no cat.

False Positive (FP): 
Reality: an image does not contains cat. 
classifier predicts: cat.

False Negative (FN): 
Reality: an image contains cat. 
classifier predicts: no cat.
```

Can anyone gives a concrete example of TP、TN、FP、FN like above, in the context of natural language processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine a hot news classifier.

True Positive (TP): 
Reality: a piece of hot news. 
classifier predicts: hot.

True Negative (TN): 
Reality: not a piece of hot news. 
classifier predicts: not hot.

False Positive (FP): 
Reality: not a piece of hot news.
classifier predicts: hot.

False Negative (FN): 
Reality: a piece of hot news. 
classifier predicts: not hot.